# SQl Error : Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get this error

> Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference

while running this query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    SUM(mla.total_current_attribute_value)
FROM 
    partstrack_machine_location_attributes mla (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN 
    #tmpInstallParts_Temp installpartdetails ON mla.machine_sequence_id = installpartdetails.InstallKitToMachineSequenceId 
                                   AND (CASE WHEN mla.machine_side_id IS NULL THEN 1  
             WHEN  mla.machine_side_id = installpartdetails.InstallKitToMachineSideId THEN 1 END
    ) = 1
INNER JOIN 
    partstrack_mes_attribute_mapping mam (NOLOCK) ON mla.mes_attribute = mam.mes_attribute_name
INNER JOIN 
    partstrack_attribute_type at (NOLOCK) ON mam.pt_attribute_id = at.pt_attribute_id 
INNER JOIN 
    partstrack_ipp_mes_attributes ima(NOLOCK) ON at.pt_attribute_id = ima.pt_attribute_id                                                   
WHERE 
    mla.active_ind = 'Y' AND
    ima.ipp_ID IN (SELECT ipp.ipp_id
                   FROM partstrack_individual_physical_part ipp
                   INNER JOIN #tmpInstallParts_Temp tmp ON (ipp.ipp_id = tmp.InstallingPartIPPId OR
               (CASE WHEN tmp.InstallingPartIPKId = '-1' THEN 1 END) = 1
                  )
GROUP BY 
    ima.ipp_id
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

This is the text of the query from the first revision of the question.
In later revisions you removed the last closing bracket `)` and the query became syntactically incorrect. You'd better check and fix the text of the question **and format the text of the query, so it is readable**.

```
SELECT TOP 1
    SUM(mla.total_current_attribute_value)
FROM
    partstrack_machine_location_attributes mla (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN #tmpInstallParts_Temp installpartdetails 
        ON mla.machine_sequence_id = installpartdetails.InstallKitToMachineSequenceId 
        AND (CASE WHEN mla.machine_side_id IS NULL THEN 1
            WHEN mla.machine_side_id = installpartdetails.InstallKitToMachineSideId THEN 1 END) = 1
    INNER JOIN partstrack_mes_attribute_mapping mam (NOLOCK) ON mla.mes_attribute = mam.mes_attribute_name
    INNER JOIN partstrack_attribute_type at (NOLOCK) ON mam.pt_attribute_id = at.pt_attribute_id
    INNER JOIN partstrack_ipp_mes_attributes ima(NOLOCK) ON at.pt_attribute_id = ima.pt_attribute_id
WHERE
    mla.active_ind = 'Y' 
    AND ima.ipp_ID IN 
    (
        Select
            ipp.ipp_id
        FROM
            partstrack_individual_physical_part ipp
            INNER JOIN #tmpInstallParts_Temp tmp 
                ON (ipp.ipp_id = tmp.InstallingPartIPPId 
                OR (CASE WHEN tmp.InstallingPartIPKId = '-1' THEN 1 END) = 1)
        GROUP BY
            ima.ipp_id
    )
```

With this formatting it is clear now that there is a subquery with `GROUP BY`.

Most likely it is just a typo: you meant to write `GROUP BY ipp.ipp_id` instead of `GROUP BY ima.ipp_id`.

---

If you really wanted to have the `GROUP BY` not in a subquery, but in the main `SELECT`, then you misplaced the closing bracket `)` and the query should look like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    SUM(mla.total_current_attribute_value)
FROM
    partstrack_machine_location_attributes mla (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN #tmpInstallParts_Temp installpartdetails 
        ON mla.machine_sequence_id = installpartdetails.InstallKitToMachineSequenceId 
        AND (CASE WHEN mla.machine_side_id IS NULL THEN 1
            WHEN mla.machine_side_id = installpartdetails.InstallKitToMachineSideId THEN 1 END) = 1
    INNER JOIN partstrack_mes_attribute_mapping mam (NOLOCK) ON mla.mes_attribute = mam.mes_attribute_name
    INNER JOIN partstrack_attribute_type at (NOLOCK) ON mam.pt_attribute_id = at.pt_attribute_id
    INNER JOIN partstrack_ipp_mes_attributes ima(NOLOCK) ON at.pt_attribute_id = ima.pt_attribute_id
WHERE
    mla.active_ind = 'Y' 
    AND ima.ipp_ID IN 
    (
        Select
            ipp.ipp_id
        FROM
            partstrack_individual_physical_part ipp
            INNER JOIN #tmpInstallParts_Temp tmp 
                ON (ipp.ipp_id = tmp.InstallingPartIPPId 
                OR (CASE WHEN tmp.InstallingPartIPKId = '-1' THEN 1 END) = 1)
    )
GROUP BY
    ima.ipp_id
```

In any case, proper formatting of the source code can really help.

Comment: I'd have thought it more likely that they didn't intend the `GROUP BY` to be inside the subquery at all. Why would they perform grouping when a) They're not performing any aggregation and b) The subquery is being used in an `IN()`, so the number of times a particular value repeats is irrelevant anyway. Basically, if the *did* intend to have it in the subquery, it's highly unclear to me *what* they thought it would achieve, and it's undoubtedly not achieving (whatever that is).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, thanks, I didn't think about it. Indeed, the fact that OP edited the question and removed the last closing bracket (making it syntactically incorrect) points to that. I added that second guess to the answer. The query itself is too messy for me to try to understand what it actually does vs what it was meant to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
Group By ima.ipp_id
```

should be applicable to outer query. Because of incorrect placement of '(' it was applying to inner query.

Now after correcting the query,it's working fine without any issues.

Final Query is :

`SELECT TOP 1
    SUM(mla.total_current_attribute_value)
FROM
    partstrack_machine_location_attributes mla (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN #tmpInstallParts_Temp installpartdetails 
        ON mla.machine_sequence_id = installpartdetails.InstallKitToMachineSequenceId 
        AND (CASE WHEN mla.machine_side_id IS NULL THEN 1
            WHEN mla.machine_side_id = installpartdetails.InstallKitToMachineSideId THEN 1 END ) = 1
    INNER JOIN partstrack_mes_attribute_mapping mam (NOLOCK) ON mla.mes_attribute = mam.mes_attribute_name
    INNER JOIN partstrack_attribute_type at (NOLOCK) ON mam.pt_attribute_id = at.pt_attribute_id
    INNER JOIN partstrack_ipp_mes_attributes ima(NOLOCK) ON at.pt_attribute_id = ima.pt_attribute_id
WHERE
    mla.active_ind = 'Y' 
    AND ima.ipp_ID IN 
    (
        Select
            ipp.ipp_id
        FROM
            partstrack_individual_physical_part ipp
            INNER JOIN #tmpInstallParts_Temp tmp 
                ON (ipp.ipp_id = tmp.InstallingPartIPPId 
                OR (CASE WHEN tmp.InstallingPartIPKId = '-1' THEN 1 END ) =1)
      )
     GROUP BY  ima.ipp_id`

Thank you all.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer, since it's the correct one now.